# Javascript/JQuery get # from url with regex or other solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I have URLs that are:

```
www.letters.com/letters/numbers/letters"
```

and

```
www.letters.com/letters/letters/numbers/symbols
```

How can I extract just the group of consecutive numbers?

Comment: you mean this `\d+` ?

Comment: What group of consecutive numbers..?

Comment: @AvinashRaj maybe...I am not very familiar with regex with jquery.  How would I write a function to grab the current url and return the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var r = 'www.foo.com/bar/12345/foobarbaz'.match(/\d+/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]) //=> 12345
```